# How can I create a if-else loop with two optional conditions

Tags: java, if-statement

I want my code to be basically like this:

```
If (something OR something else)

{
    Do magical things;
}

else

{    
    cry me a river;
}
```

How can I do it so there are two optional conditions, meaning both do not need to be true (just one) in order for the loop to do 'magical' things.

Comment: You put another if loop nested inside the 'do magical things'  loop which checks for those conditions.

Comment: @Jhecht: There are no loops here at all, and no need for another `if` statement... all that's needed is the `||` operator...

Comment: In basics of if statements you are correct.  but 'optional' means that other things are required to do magical things.

Comment: Do you want to also execute magical things if both conditions are true? If yes you can use *or* operator `||`, if you want to accept case when only one condition is true ant other is false then you may need to use exclusive or (XOR) operator `^`.

Comment: `if (a || b) { ... }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost answered your own question. :)

Type simply:

```
if((first_logical_value) || (second_logical_value)){
    // ... do magical things
} else {
    // ... do other things
}
```

If in case of two false values you don't wont to do anything - skip else part of this statement. You can find things like this searching internet resources, e.g.:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html
- http://www.erpgreat.com/java/java-boolean-logical-operators.htm